# Center input horizontally in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this has been answered 100 times, but none of the existing solutions seem to work for me.

I want to center an input field horizontally in a div. Why is horizontal centering such a pain?!?!? The parent div may change in size based on screen size, so margin percentages don't work.

HTML

```
  <div class="select" id="avatar">
    <h4>Please enter your name.</h4>
    <!-- Object i want to center-->
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="playerName">
    </div>

    <h4>And Select Your Ship</h4>
    <img class="avatars" id="ship1" src="images/spaceship1.png">
    <img class="avatars" id="ship2" src="images/spaceship2.png">
    <img class="avatars" id="ship3" src="images/spaceship3.png">
    <img class="avatars" id="ship4" src="images/spaceship4.png">
    <button class="btn" id="submitPlayer">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

parents CSS

```
    .select {
        background-color: white;
        z-index: 200;
        padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Krona One', sans-serif;
        border: medium dashed green;
        margin-left: 25%;
        margin-right: 25%;
    }
```

I also want to center this one, and I assume it will be the same solution, but it has no parent, besides body.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="text-center" type="text" id="word">
</div>
```

Comment: the text-center don't do anything, they're stubbornly clinging to the left side of the screen.

Comment: I would first say that yes, this already looks centered to me: https://jsfiddle.net/john_h/s126ur5c/ For div elements, set your `margin: 0 auto;` on the divs that you want centered.  Doing so will will center your div because the margin on the top and bottom will be 0, and left and right will automatically calculate evenly to be in the middle.

Comment: I want the input box to be in the middle of the div. the text inside of it, I don't care about

Comment: @john_h weird, the exact same code on my computer, has the input field stuck to the left side of the parent div, there must be some other conflicting css messing it up then, hmmm

Comment: could bootstrap be screwing it up somehow?

Comment: it was input-group, when I deleted it, it centered

Comment: Yes, there is input-group display table. Set it display: block.

Comment: yes because input group is for an input group, not an input alone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use Bootstrap's `center-block` class..

```
<div class="input-group center-block">
  <input class="center-block" type="text" id="word">
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/sTboTk5CvU

Comment: because i was unaware of its existence! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

inputs and button are like img, you can display them as block and use margin:auto; so they stand alone and in the middle without using 100% of the width/space avalaible :

```css
.select {
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 200;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Krona One', sans-serif;
  border: medium dashed green;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}
button.btn#submitPlayer {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="select" id="avatar">
  <h4>Please enter your name.</h4>
  <!-- Object i want to center-->
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="playerName">
  </div>

  <h4>And Select Your Ship</h4>
  <img class="avatars" id="ship1" src="images/spaceship1.png">
  <img class="avatars" id="ship2" src="images/spaceship2.png">
  <img class="avatars" id="ship3" src="images/spaceship3.png">
  <img class="avatars" id="ship4" src="images/spaceship4.png">
  <button class="btn" id="submitPlayer">Submit</button>
</div>
```

and you may do the same with input :

```css
.input-group,
input#word.text-center{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="text-center" type="text" id="word">
</div>
```